# Which is more efficient: html video or javascript slider?

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video

I just wondering about following situation:

## Description

Pictures slider placed on website by: **HTML5 Video element** or **Javascript slider** (It does matter which solution will be chosen: raw javascript or libraries).

### Assumptions

1. One slider in fixed place on a website
2. Fixed numbers of pictures in a slider
3. Pictures don't change
4. Browser support doesn't matter

### Parameters influencing on result

1. Usage of CPU/GPU
2. Loading speed

   1. Weight of file or files
   2. Ready time to show

### Problem to solve

*Which way is more efficient?*

Have guys any experiences in this topic?

Cheers!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "Javascript slider" or "pictures slider", but have you considered trying it both ways? You can use your browser's profiler, watch your system resource usage, or just see which seems more responsive. Of course that doesn't tell you the answers for every system, but if you try it on a couple different browsers on different computers, you'll probably have enough data to make a decision.

Comment: I mean pictures slider like this one: http://www.jssor.com For example: slider with pictures is placed as background at full width. I just wondering which way in this case will be more efficient/faster so I asked about yours experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, based on the sliders you referred to at [jssor.com](http://jssor.com), it seems like a slider should be much more efficient in most ways. If there are no animations except when the user is moving the slider, then there should be no CPU/GPU usage either (assuming the slider is implemented efficiently). A video playing in the background will always use some CPU/GPU. If it's a format that most GPUs can accelerate (MPEG-2 or H.264), the CPU usage may be very small, but you can't count on that.

Of course most of those slider demos have animations going all the time. That will use CPU too.

As far as loading/startup time, a few JPEG images will usually be *much* smaller than a video file. The slider should start up at least as fast as a video, and use a lot less bandwidth.

As usual, the only final answer to "which is more efficient?" is "Try both and see."